# Relationship no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Fala galera, estou começando a utilizar o laravel e estou com um problema na hora de selecionar alguns dados.

Tenho as seguintes tabelas: `users`, `jobs`, `projects`, `job_user`.

- A relação da tabela de `users` e `jobs` é de **muitos pra muitos** e é
  feita através da tabela auxiliar `job_user`.
- Um `job` pertence a um `project`.

Relações na Model Job:

```
public function scopeAuthUser($q)
{
    return $q->whereHas('users', function($q){
        $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    });
}

public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

---

Relações na Model Project:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function jobs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
}
```

---

Relações na Model User:

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class);
}
```

---

JobsController:

```
public function index()
{
    $jobs = $this->job->authUser()->with('project.company')->get();

    return view('jobs.index', compact('jobs'));
}
```

---

A dúvida é a seguinte, como faço pra na ProjectsController, mostrar apenas Projects que tenham Jobs que o usuário esteja vinculado?

Comment: Me parece que você já fez isso resolvendo com `scope` :: `$jobs = $this->job->authUser()->with('project.company')->get();` ???

Comment: Ele me retorna um array de jobs, que dentro de cada um tem um project, eu preciso trazer apenas os projects nessa consulta...

Comment: Pera um pouco, então está trazendo corretamente?.

Comment: `$jobs = $this->job->authUser()->project` ???

Comment: Sim, na verdade eu estava me enrolando mesmo, pois ficar fazendo estas validações em uma controller ficava muito "desorganizado" pra mim, hoje comecei um curso de ACL e já me sanou várias dúvidas inclusive esta, muito obrigado pelas respostas!